# Trouble declaring an array using symbolic constant

Tags: c++, arduino

This code will not compile:

```
#ifndef RemoteControl_h
#define RemoteControl_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class RemoteControl
{
    public:
        RemoteControl();
        ~RemoteControl();

        static void prev_track();
        static void next_track();
        static void play_pause_track();
        static void mute();
        static void vol_up();
        static void vol_down();

        void respond(int code);
        void add_code(int code, void (*func)());
    private:
        boolean active = true;
        struct pair {
            int _code;
            void (*_func)();
        };
        const int max = 1000;
        int database_length = 0;
        pair database[max]; //This line doesn't compile unless I use a literal constant instead of "max"

};
#endif
```

But if I put the section below in the constructor for the class instead it works fine.

```
const int max = 1000;
int database_length = 0;
pair database[max];
```

Am I not allowed to declare an array within a class in c++ and use a virtual constant as the length? I am working in arduino if that makes a difference, but I expect that I am not understanding something with the c++ language since this is a standard .h file. Oh and the problem isn't the .cpp file because I completely removed it with the same results: compiles with literal constant length but not virtual constant length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C or C++,try using `malloc()` in `stdlib.h`, `cstdlib` for c++. Don't forget `free()`

```
const int max = 1000;
struct pair *ptr = malloc(sizeof(pair) * max); // allocated 1000 pairs
free(ptr); // when the amount of memory is not needed anymore
```

Comment: arduino does not support the use of "new" keyword at least as far as I can tell. For the first example are you then suggesting that I do this then?                           const int max = 1000;
  int database_length = 0;
  int *ptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * max); 
  int database[];
  database = ptr;

Comment: I am a little rusty on that. Basically I add the offset to ptr then dereference and assign to that right? Assign 3 to index 2 like this?:     *(ptr+2) = 3

Comment: `*(ptr+2) = 3` same as `ptr[2] = 3`. You can use and behave it like an array. @j_v_wow_d

Comment: Great. I just need "free(ptr)" in my destructor then and I should be good to go right?

Comment: when you don't need the memory (allocation) anymore destroy it. yes. @j_v_wow_d

Answer (score 1):

Let me first clear a few things up for you.

1. In `C`, a `const` variable is considered as `const`-qualified, it is not a compile-time constant value (unlike an integer literal, which is a compile time constant value). So, as per the rules for normal array size specification, you cannot even use a `const` variable in this case.
2. In `C`, we *may* have the provision to use [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which enables us to use syntax like `pair database[max]` even if `max` is not a `const` variable but that is again some optional feature of the compiler (as per `C11`).
3. In `C++`, we can use a `const` variable as the size of array, as in `C++`, a `const` variable is a compile time constant.

So, to answer your question:

- In `C`, your code will be ok if your compiler supports VLA. and even if `max` is not `const`.
- In `C++`, there is no VLA, but it *maybe* supported as a gnu extension. If `max` is `const`, it will be ok.

Comment: Arduino's compiler does not support it within the class body the way it seems but it works inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is to just take the

```
const int max = 1000;
```

out of the class and put it above the class.

Even better would be to ensure that it is a compile-time constant like so:

```
constexpr int max = 1000;
```